# Store files in a data-store - audio and video files

Tags: mysql, mongodb, amazon-s3, hdfs, gridfs

I'm looking out for various options to store files (audio and video) in a data-store. Some of the options explored are:

1) mysql - blob type

2) mongo db - BSON (for files less than 16 MB) and GridFS for file size > 16 MB.

3) HDFS

4) AWS S3 bucket

What will the good fit to store ~1 Million files, ~50,000 hits/day, max file size = 20 MB.

Comment: If the files are mostly over 4 KB, why not store them in the file system?

Comment: @rid yes, that can be done. here I'm trying to evaluate various option along with merits and demerits that may occur on load increase or in terms of availability, etc.